Is returning a reference to a managed memory a malpractice?
Given this code:
class Clazz {
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<int> something;

 public:
  Clazz() : something(std::make_shared<int>(0)) {}

  int &getSomething() {
    return *something;
  }
}

It leads to dangling references since the obtained reference might point at some moment to deallocated memory. For me it seems like a mirror of a dangling pointer scenario, but I failed to find any sources on that.

The reference is not dangling as long as the Clazz object is alive (and something is not reset). So there could be scenarios where is it valid. Why would you want to do that is a diffrent issue. You haven't given us enough contexts to give advise.

Let's make no assumptions about the lifespan of the Clazz object.

There are many cases in the standard library where a reference to memory owned by the class is returned. For example, std::vector::operator[], and also std::shared_ptr::operator* which you used here.

If the Clazz object dies, the reference could be indeed dangling (but since it's a shared_ptr, there could be other shared owners keeping something alive).

The bottom line is that the reference is valid as long as the object managed by the shared_ptr is alive.

If we should make no assumptions about the lifetime of clazz, then no reference that depends on its lifetime should ever be returned. Doesn't matter if it's "managed memory" or not. In reality, we always make these assumptions. A healthy rule of thumb is: if you get a reference from an instance method, assume that it will remain valid exactly as long as the instance you got it from. If your class behaves accordingly then you're fine.

Rust has lifetime in the type, C++ hasn't.

@tjzel The lifetime of the referred int depends in part with the lifetime of the associated Clazz instance. If we can make no assumptions about the lifetime of the Clazz object, and have no more information about other instances of shared_ptr to that int, then we can't make answer anything about the validity of the reference.

If you're using std::shared_ptr, pass it around by value.  That's the whole point of it.  Only return by reference if you can guarantee that the object in question won't disappear out from under you.

There is, again, a lot of "depends" and personal preferences with this kind of stuff.
Lifetimes of "raw" pointers always need to be explicit.
Things are easy if you have a smartpointer, and you give your internal functions raw pointers (or references) -- you just have to remember to not store these pointers anywhere. And since you're holding the smartpointer, all the functions you call with the raw pointer will have no issues.
Things are slightly more complex when you return such pointers from an API. Even if it's my own API, I like to document it accordingly, such as
/* ...
 * has<T> returns a pointer to the stored item, or nullptr.  This
 * pointer is valid until a yield.
 */

to remind people and/or myself to not keep that pointer around.
In other cases, I might return pointers to internal buffers, telling people that the data won't change until the next call is made.
I'm not always writing down everything. As an example, if I return a pointer to an internal buffer, I don't generally mention that this pointer will become invalid when the object is destroyed. I'm generally assuming some level of expertise from users, and only document stuff that's not immediately obvious.
Also note that raw pointers, in my book, have a validity -- but no free function associated with them. They just turn invalid at some defined point in time, but users never have to free them -- I'd always return something more advanced if such things need to be cleaned up.
